# Game Development using C#.Net

Tags: c#, software-engineering, .net, platform

I'm a  ASP as well as C#.Net Developer. I love playing Games and willing to Create one. 
I'm a new bi in this Arena. 
So can you Help me on How to Create a Game using C#.Net??
Or is there any course or a platform using which I can Develop one?
Can you suggest me different platforms using which we Develop Games!

Comment: "How do I get started?" questions are off topic, as are "what technology should I use?" questions.

Comment: Okay. I'm sorry as I don't know that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XNA would be the obvious choice for a C# beginner. I suggest installing the XNA GameStudio and getting a copy of the book [XNA Game Development by Example: Beginner's Guide](http://www.packtpub.com/xna-4-0-game-development-by-example-beginners-guide/book). It introduces you to all the important basics and concepts and leaves you well equipped to become a game developer.

If you want, you can also use [Unity](http://unity3d.com/). It's a 3D engine, but allows for 2D development as well, and the scripts your game uses can be written in C#.

Comment: I second XNA, it's the most logical choice for someone with .NET experience. It's meant to follow the .NET framework implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest 'Mogre', currently for windows (c# port of Ogre3d).
(it does not support Monodevelop at this time).
there are many tutorials and samples for Mogre.

http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/MOGRE

Comment: see monogame, cross platform alternative of xna.